# How to Sqoop --query with Where Clause (VARCHAR filter)?

Tags: oracle, sqoop

So... how do you do it?

```
--query 'SELECT (...) WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'VARCHAR_FILTER' AND $CONDITIONS'
```

I've tried a bunch of combinations, search the interwebz but I didn't find anyone with this situation. Everyone is using numbers instead of varchars...

How to you use the --query form, and the where clause has VARCHARS?

Thanks!

EDIT:

SOLVED! Correct Syntax is the following:

```
--query "select COLUMNS FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'VARCHAR' AND \$CONDITIONS"
```

The shell was identifying $CONDITIONS as a Linux variable.

Comment: You should answer your question with the answer button, not by edit. [answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, use double quotes for the query, and single quotes for strings:

```
"SELECT (...) WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'VARCHAR_FILTER' AND \$CONDITIONS"
```

Comment: If I do that I have this problem

java.io.IOException: Query [select Fields FROM table WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'varchar' AND ] must contain '$CONDITIONS' in WHERE clause.

Comment: Sintex correct, but was missing escape \$CONDITIONS

Comment: Afirmative. It now works, but just had the escape \$CONDITIONS or the shell will understand that $ is a linux variable.

Comment: Great . Accept this answer then .

Comment: Can't mate... I don't have 15 points of reputation to do that. :(

Comment: Not upvote, below the arrow ^ there is a `V` mark . anyone can do that. @JoaoBarreto

Comment: YOu should Edit your answer and add the \ to the $Conditions in order to be 100% correct :P